# New iOS and Safari remove classes added via script in jQuery on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll, ios8

since the last iOS Update (8+), the Safari "destroys" a jQuery script I use for my mobile navigations.
The mark up is a normal unordered list, generated from Contao.

Now, when I open my page on iOS 8+, the script loads normally, I can open my navigation without a problem, but as soon as I scroll down a bit, it just closes my menu - not even with the toggle slide animation, it just disappears.

**My Markup:**

```
<div class="nav-btn"> <!-- burger icon for menu interaction !-->
     <span></span>
     <span></span>
     <span></span>
     <span></span>
</div>
<div class="mod_navigation main-menu"> <!-- menu !-->
     <ul class="level_1 clearfix"> <!-- main menu list !-->
         <!-- list elements and anchors following here !-->
         <li><a href="..." title="...">...</a></li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

**My jQuery:**

```
function hideDiv(){
if ($(window).width() > 941) { $(".main-menu .level_1").show(); } else { $(".main-menu .level_1").hide(); }
}

$(document).ready(function(){
hideDiv();
console.log('logging');
$('.header .nav-btn').click(function () {
$('.main-menu .level_1').stop(true,true).slideToggle(); 
$('.nav-btn').toggleClass( "open" );
});
   $(window).resize(function(){
        hideDiv();
        $('.nav-btn').removeClass("open");
    });
});
```

Does anyone use a similar script and/or can tell me why it's closing my menu?

I also created a JSFiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/940293vw/1/

I read an article about how they changed the scroll event in iOS8, but that didn't go further into the detail about why they should just stop my script when scrolling.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Guys stop being lazyIf you want us to help, try using your fiddle and see if it reproduces the issue. In your case you didn't even include jQuery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix it pretty soon after asking this question, forgot to answer it. Anyway. This worked, for anyone encountering the same issue.

```
    /* ios 8+*/
var widthwdw = 0;

$(window).load(function(){
   widthwdw = $(window).width();
});

$(window).resize(function(){

  if(widthwdw != $(window).width()){
    //Do something
    widthwdw = $(window).width();
    hideDiv();
    $('.header .nav-btn').removeClass("open");
  }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this exact issue. What I ended up doing was toggling a class that included display:block; when slidetoggle was complete.

I don't know the reason, but mobile safari wipes out inlnie styles added by jQuery functions when the user scrolls. But it doesn't seem to wipe out classes added by jQuery. Mobile safari works in mysterious ways, and I'm equally curious as to why this is

The code should be something like this:

```
  $("#button").click(function(){
    $("nav").slideToggle(function(){
        $("nav").toggleClass('iosfix');
    });
  });
```

Then in my css -

```
.iosfix {
   display:block;
}
```

Hope that helps!